Got error "Serializer failed" while serializing to AVRO with a schema including optional fields
I am producing data to Kafka in AVRO format.
I created a schema by
curl --location 'https://confluent-schema-registry.example.com/subjects/production.iot.device.avro-value/versions' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json' \
--data '{
    "schema": "{\"type\": \"record\", \"name\": \"device\", \"fields\":[{ \"name\": \"status\", \"type\": \"string\"},{ \"name\": \"location\", \"type\": \"string\"},{ \"name\": \"type\", \"type\": \"string\"},{ \"name\": \"temperature\", \"type\": \"long\"},{ \"name\": \"humidity\", \"type\": \"double\"},{ \"name\": \"battery\", \"type\": \"long\"},{ \"name\": \"signal_strength\", \"type\": \"long\"},{ \"name\": \"mode\", \"type\": \"string\"},{ \"name\": \"active\", \"type\": \"boolean\"}]}"
}'

I am using

avro-c 1.11.3
libserdes 8.0.0

Below code can succeed writing data to Kafka:
#include <avro.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <librdkafka/rdkafka.h>
#include <libserdes/serdes-avro.h>
#include <libserdes/serdes.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "config.c"

#define ARR_SIZE(arr) (sizeof((arr)) / sizeof((arr[0])))

static volatile bool is_running = true;

static void delivery_report(rd_kafka_t *kafka_handle,
                            const rd_kafka_message_t *rkmessage, void *opaque) {
  if (rkmessage->err) {
    g_error("Message delivery failed: %s", rd_kafka_err2str(rkmessage->err));
  }
}

void signal_handler(int signal) {
  if (signal == SIGINT || signal == SIGTERM) {
    is_running = false;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  rd_kafka_t *producer;
  rd_kafka_conf_t *conf;
  serdes_conf_t *serdes_conf;
  serdes_t *serdes;
  char errstr[512];

  if (argc != 2) {
    g_error("Usage: %s <config.ini>", argv[0]);
  }

  const char *config_file = argv[1];

  g_autoptr(GError) error = NULL;
  g_autoptr(GKeyFile) key_file = g_key_file_new();
  if (!g_key_file_load_from_file(key_file, config_file, G_KEY_FILE_NONE, &error)) {
    g_error("Error loading config file: %s", error->message);
  }

  conf = rd_kafka_conf_new();
  load_config_group(conf, key_file, "default");

  rd_kafka_conf_set(conf, "queue.buffering.max.messages", "10000000", NULL, 0);
  rd_kafka_conf_set(conf, "queue.buffering.max.kbytes", "10485760", NULL, 0);
  rd_kafka_conf_set(conf, "batch.size", "65536", NULL, 0);
  rd_kafka_conf_set(conf, "linger.ms", "5", NULL, 0);
  rd_kafka_conf_set_dr_msg_cb(conf, delivery_report);

  producer = rd_kafka_new(RD_KAFKA_PRODUCER, conf, errstr, sizeof(errstr));
  if (!producer) {
    g_error("Failed to create new producer: %s", errstr);
  }

  signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
  signal(SIGTERM, signal_handler);

  serdes_conf = serdes_conf_new(
      NULL, 0, "schema.registry.url",
      "https://confluent-schema-registry.example.com", NULL);

  serdes = serdes_new(serdes_conf, errstr, sizeof(errstr));
  if (!serdes) {
    g_error("Failed to create serdes instance: %s", errstr);
  }

  const char *topic = "production.iot.device.avro";
  const char *schema_name = "production.iot.device.avro-value";
  serdes_schema_t *serdes_schema =
      serdes_schema_get(serdes, schema_name, -1, errstr, sizeof(errstr));
  if (!serdes_schema) {
    g_error("Failed to retrieve AVRO schema: %s", errstr);
  }

  const char *device_ids[6] = {"device1", "device2", "device3",
                               "device4", "device5", "device6"};
  const char *status_list[3] = {"online", "offline", "maintenance"};
  const char *locations[3] = {"locationA", "locationB", "locationC"};
  const char *types[3] = {"type1", "type2", "type3"};

  srandom(time(NULL));  // Seed the random number generator

  while (is_running) {
    const char *key = device_ids[random() % ARR_SIZE(device_ids)];

    const char *status = status_list[random() % ARR_SIZE(status_list)];
    const char *location = locations[random() % ARR_SIZE(locations)];
    const char *type = types[random() % ARR_SIZE(types)];
    double temperature = ((double)random() / RAND_MAX) * 100.0 - 50.0;
    double humidity = ((double)random() / RAND_MAX);
    int battery = random() % 101;
    int signal_strength = random() % 101;
    const char *mode = (random() % 2) ? "manual" : "auto";
    bool active = (random() % 2);

    avro_schema_t schema = serdes_schema_avro(serdes_schema);
    avro_value_iface_t *record_class = avro_generic_class_from_schema(schema);

    avro_value_t record;
    avro_generic_value_new(record_class, &record);

    avro_value_t field;
    if (avro_value_get_by_name(&record, "status", &field, NULL) == 0) {
      avro_value_set_string(&field, status);
    }
    if (avro_value_get_by_name(&record, "location", &field, NULL) == 0) {
      avro_value_set_string(&field, location);
    }
    if (avro_value_get_by_name(&record, "type", &field, NULL) == 0) {
      avro_value_set_string(&field, type);
    }
    if (avro_value_get_by_name(&record, "temperature", &field, NULL) == 0) {
      avro_value_set_long(&field, temperature);
    }
    if (avro_value_get_by_name(&record, "humidity", &field, NULL) == 0) {
      avro_value_set_double(&field, humidity);
    }
    if (avro_value_get_by_name(&record, "battery", &field, NULL) == 0) {
      avro_value_set_long(&field, battery);
    }
    if (avro_value_get_by_name(&record, "signal_strength", &field, NULL) == 0) {
      avro_value_set_long(&field, signal_strength);
    }
    if (avro_value_get_by_name(&record, "mode", &field, NULL) == 0) {
      avro_value_set_string(&field, mode);
    }
    if (avro_value_get_by_name(&record, "active", &field, NULL) == 0) {
      avro_value_set_boolean(&field, active);
    }

    void *avro_payload = NULL;
    size_t avro_size;
    serdes_err_t serr = serdes_schema_serialize_avro(serdes_schema, &record, &avro_payload, &avro_size, errstr, sizeof(errstr));
    if (serr != SERDES_ERR_OK) {
      g_error("Failed to serialize data: %s", serdes_err2str(serr));
    }

    rd_kafka_resp_err_t err;
    err = rd_kafka_producev(producer, RD_KAFKA_V_TOPIC(topic),
                            RD_KAFKA_V_MSGFLAGS(RD_KAFKA_MSG_F_COPY),
                            RD_KAFKA_V_KEY((void *)key, strlen(key)),
                            RD_KAFKA_V_VALUE(avro_payload, avro_size),
                            RD_KAFKA_V_OPAQUE(NULL), RD_KAFKA_V_END);

    if (err) {
      g_error("Failed to produce to topic %s: %s", topic,
              rd_kafka_err2str(err));
    }

    free(avro_payload);
    avro_value_decref(&record);
    rd_kafka_poll(producer, 0);
    g_usleep(50);  // μs
  }

  g_message("Flushing final messages ...");
  rd_kafka_flush(producer, 10 * 1000);

  if (rd_kafka_outq_len(producer) > 0) {
    g_error("%d message(s) were not delivered", rd_kafka_outq_len(producer));
  }

  g_message("Producer stopped.");
  rd_kafka_destroy(producer);
  serdes_schema_destroy(serdes_schema);
  serdes_destroy(serdes);
  return 0;
}

Now, for full schema compatibility, I tried to make each field optional. I deleted the old schema and recreated a new one by
curl --location 'https://confluent-schema-registry.example.com/subjects/production.iot.device.avro-value/versions' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json' \
--data '{
    "schema": "{\"type\": \"record\", \"name\": \"device\", \"fields\":[{ \"name\": \"status\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"string\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"location\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"string\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"type\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"string\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"temperature\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"long\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"humidity\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"double\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"battery\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"long\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"signal_strength\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"long\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"mode\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"string\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"active\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"boolean\"], \"default\": null}]}"
}'

But now same code will fail at the line serdes_err_t serr = serdes_schema_serialize_avro(schema, &record, &avro_payload, &avro_size, errstr, sizeof(errstr)); and returns error:

Failed to serialize data: Serializer failed

Based on my research, "Serializer failed" is corresponding to SERDES_ERR_SERIALIZER, and this part in the library libserdes triggered this error. The function avro_value_sizeof inside failed, and here is the avro_value_sizeof source code.
Based on this info, I added this section to reproduce:
int aerr = avro_value_sizeof(&record, &avro_size);
if (aerr) {
  printf("%s\n", strerror(aerr));
}

I can see it prints out

Invalid argument

However, I am not sure what caused this issue. Any guide would be appreciate, thanks!

UPADTE 1
In my origoinal code, I added
void print_serdes_schema(serdes_schema_t *serdes_schema) {
    if (!serdes_schema) {
        printf("serdes_schema is NULL.\n");
        return;
    }

    const char *schema_name = serdes_schema_name(serdes_schema);
    if (schema_name) {
        printf("schema_name: %s\n", schema_name);
    } else {
        printf("Failed to retrieve schema_name.\n");
    }

    int schema_id = serdes_schema_id(serdes_schema);
    printf("schema_id: %d\n", schema_id);

    const char *schema_definition = serdes_schema_definition(serdes_schema);
    if (schema_definition) {
        printf("serdes_schema: %s\n", schema_definition);
    } else {
        printf("Failed to retrieve serdes_schema.\n");
    }
}

print_schema_info(serdes_schema); returns:
schema_name: production.iot.device.avro-value
schema_id: 17
serdes_schema: {"type":"record","name":"device","fields":[{"name":"status","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"location","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"type","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"temperature","type":["null","long"],"default":null},{"name":"humidity","type":["null","double"],"default":null},{"name":"battery","type":["null","long"],"default":null},{"name":"signal_strength","type":["null","long"],"default":null},{"name":"mode","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"active","type":["null","boolean"],"default":null}]}

It means function serdes_schema_get works well.

UPADTE 2
In my origoinal code, I added
void print_avro_schema(avro_schema_t schema) {
  char schema_str [8192];
  avro_writer_t writer = avro_writer_memory(schema_str, 8192);
  avro_schema_to_json(schema, writer);
  printf("schema: %s\n", schema_str);
}

print_avro_schema(schema); will print
{"type":"record","name":"device","fields":[{"name":"status","type":[{"type":"null"},{"type":"string"}]},{"name":"location","type":[{"type":"null"},{"type":"string"}]},{"name":"type","type":[{"type":"null"},{"type":"string"}]},{"name":"temperature","type":[{"type":"null"},{"type":"long"}]},{"name":"humidity","type":[{"type":"null"},{"type":"double"}]},{"name":"battery","type":[{"type":"null"},{"type":"long"}]},{"name":"signal_strength","type":[{"type":"null"},{"type":"long"}]},{"name":"mode","type":[{"type":"null"},{"type":"string"}]},{"name":"active","type":[{"type":"null"},{"type":"boolean"}]}]}

Note it does not have "default":null inside.
When I create a local schema
const char LOCAL_SCHEMA_WITH_OPTIONAL[] = "{\"type\": \"record\", \"name\": \"hongbo_test\", \"fields\":[{ \"name\": \"status\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"string\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"location\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"string\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"type\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"string\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"temperature\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"long\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"humidity\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"double\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"battery\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"long\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"signal_strength\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"long\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"mode\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"string\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"active\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"boolean\"], \"default\": null}]}";
avro_schema_t local_schema;
if (avro_schema_from_json_literal(LOCAL_SCHEMA_WITH_OPTIONAL, &local_schema)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Unable to parse person schema\n");
  return 1;
}
print_avro_schema(local_schema);

It prints exact same. So I guess "default":null not included avro_schema_t type variable is expected (?)
Now to reproduce the error, the code can be simplified to
const char LOCAL_SCHEMA_WITH_OPTIONAL[] = "{\"type\": \"record\", \"name\": \"hongbo_test\", \"fields\":[{ \"name\": \"status\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"string\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"location\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"string\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"type\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"string\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"temperature\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"long\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"humidity\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"double\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"battery\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"long\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"signal_strength\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"long\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"mode\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"string\"], \"default\": null},{ \"name\": \"active\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"boolean\"], \"default\": null}]}";
// const char LOCAL_SCHEMA_WITHOUT_OPTIONAL[] = "{\"type\": \"record\", \"name\": \"hongbo_test\", \"fields\":[{ \"name\": \"status\", \"type\": \"string\"},{ \"name\": \"location\", \"type\": \"string\"},{ \"name\": \"type\", \"type\": \"string\"},{ \"name\": \"temperature\", \"type\": \"long\"},{ \"name\": \"humidity\", \"type\": \"double\"},{ \"name\": \"battery\", \"type\": \"long\"},{ \"name\": \"signal_strength\", \"type\": \"long\"},{ \"name\": \"mode\", \"type\": \"string\"},{ \"name\": \"active\", \"type\": \"boolean\"}]}";
avro_schema_t local_schema;
if (avro_schema_from_json_literal(LOCAL_SCHEMA_WITH_OPTIONAL, &local_schema)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Unable to parse person schema\n");
  return 1;
}
print_avro_schema(local_schema);

avro_value_iface_t *record_class = avro_generic_class_from_schema(local_schema);

avro_value_t field;
avro_value_t record;
avro_generic_value_new(record_class, &record);

if (avro_value_get_by_name(&record, "status", &field, NULL) == 0) {
  if (avro_value_set_string(&field, status) != 0) {
    printf("avro_value_set_string failed\n");
  }
}
if (avro_value_get_by_name(&record, "location", &field, NULL) == 0) {
  if (avro_value_set_string(&field, location) != 0) {
    printf("avro_value_set_string failed\n");
  }
}
if (avro_value_get_by_name(&record, "type", &field, NULL) == 0) {
  if (avro_value_set_string(&field, type) != 0) {
    printf("avro_value_set_string failed\n");
  }
}
if (avro_value_get_by_name(&record, "temperature", &field, NULL) == 0) {
  if (avro_value_set_long(&field, temperature) != 0) {
    printf("avro_value_set_long failed\n");
  }
}
if (avro_value_get_by_name(&record, "humidity", &field, NULL) == 0) {
  if (avro_value_set_double(&field, humidity) != 0) {
    printf("avro_value_set_double failed\n");
  }
}
if (avro_value_get_by_name(&record, "battery", &field, NULL) == 0) {
  if (avro_value_set_long(&field, battery) != 0) {
    printf("avro_value_set_long failed\n");
  }
}
if (avro_value_get_by_name(&record, "signal_strength", &field, NULL) == 0) {
  if (avro_value_set_long(&field, signal_strength) != 0) {
    printf("avro_value_set_long failed\n");
  }
}
if (avro_value_get_by_name(&record, "mode", &field, NULL) == 0) {
  if (avro_value_set_string(&field, mode) != 0) {
    printf("avro_value_set_string failed\n");
  }
}
if (avro_value_get_by_name(&record, "active", &field, NULL) == 0) {
  if (avro_value_set_boolean(&field, active) != 0) {
    printf("avro_value_set_boolean failed\n");
  }
}

// For debugging
char *record_str;
avro_value_to_json(&record, 1, &record_str);
printf("record: %s\n", record_str);

void *avro_payload = NULL;
size_t avro_size;

// For debugging, this `avro_value_sizeof` is where it failed inside next function `serdes_schema_serialize_avro`
int aerr = avro_value_sizeof(&record, &avro_size);
if (aerr) {
  printf("avro_value_sizeof: %s\n", strerror(aerr));
}


When I use LOCAL_SCHEMA_WITHOUT_OPTIONAL, it will print something like
record: {"status": "online", "location": "locationA", "type": "type1", "temperature": 38, "humidity": 0.76082854986229376, "battery": 40, "signal_strength": 84, "mode": "auto", "active": true}


When I use LOCAL_SCHEMA_WITH_OPTIONAL, it will print something like
avro_value_set_string failed
avro_value_set_string failed
avro_value_set_string failed
avro_value_set_long failed
avro_value_set_double failed
avro_value_set_long failed
avro_value_set_long failed
avro_value_set_string failed
avro_value_set_boolean failed
record: (null)
avro_value_sizeof: Invalid argument



If "default":null not included avro_schema_t type variable is expected, the question would become how to create a proper record when the value is optional can be null.

Does the schema_get call work as expected? Your topic name ends in json, but the schema subject says avro

Hi @OneCricketeer, sorry for the typo earlier when I was redacting information. I have fixed it in my question. The serdes_schema_get function works well. I have also added the result in the question.

I found the error, basically when a value can be optional, it is a Union type (the first type in Union is null, the second type is string, long, double, boolean, etc.).
I need add an extra avro_value_set_branch step.
Here is the  avro_value_set_branch function prototype:
int avro_value_set_branch(avro_value_t *union_val, int discriminant, avro_value_t *branch);

So basically, this part of code
if (avro_value_get_by_name(&record, "status", &field, NULL) == 0) {
  avro_value_set_string(&field, status);
}
if (avro_value_get_by_name(&record, "location", &field, NULL) == 0) {
  avro_value_set_string(&field, location);
}
// ...

needs to update to something like
if (avro_value_get_by_name(&record, "status", &field, NULL) == 0) {
  if (avro_value_set_branch(&field, 1, &field) == 0) {
    avro_value_set_string(&field, status);
  }
}
if (avro_value_get_by_name(&record, "location", &field, NULL) == 0) {
  if (avro_value_set_branch(&field, 1, &field) == 0) {
    avro_value_set_string(&field, location);
  }
}
// ...

Now the data can successfully write to Kafka:

